# How are /dev/dm-0 and /dev/mapper/control created, when using lvm?

Tags: linux, lvm, udev, device-mapper

AFAIK, `lvm` implementations are in userspace, and it basically sets up mapping tables using kernel's device mapper mechanism (`dm-mod` module), via the `dmsetup` command.

Is it correct that this is the sequence of events that eventually leads to `/dev/dm-x`?

- a block device comes online
- a `udev` rule is triggered, which scans the block device's partitions, and recognizes a lvm volume group/logical volume meta data in the first several sectors in the partitions(via `dmsetup`?)
- the `udev` rule then loads the `dm-mod` module, and calls dmsetup to make a new device named `/dev/dm-x`, and sets up the mapping table using the meta data above mentioned above.
- some other `udev` rules create symlinks, such as `/dev/mapper/vg_name-lv_name`

Here are the questions,

- which specific `udev` rule loads the `dm-mod` module?
- which specific `udev` rule creates the file `/dev/mapper/control`?
- which specific `udev` rule creates `/dev/dm-x` files?

I know roughly they should come from `xx-dm.rules`(`xx-dm-lvm.rules` only adds `/dev/vg_name/lv_name` symlinks later), but which lines in that file do exactly those things?

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence of events is mostly correct, with the following exceptions:

- `udev` does not trigger the loading of the `dm_mod` kernel module, `kmod` does that.
- the most relevant udev rule with LVM is the one that causes `pvscan` to be called on new disk- and partition-like block devices. `pvscan` is usually part of a single multi-call binary that contains all the LVM tools, and uses `libdevmapper` to communicate with device-mapper directly, without calling `dmsetup`.
- the LVM tools binary is also directly responsible for reading the LVM metadata and specifying the symlink names, although `udev` is the low-level worker that actually ends up with the job of creating the links.

> which specific `udev` rule loads the `dm-mod` module?

`udev` is not involved here. This is handled by the `devtmpfs` filesystem and the `kmod` subsystem. When anything attempts to access a non-existing `/dev/mapper/control` device, `devtmpfs` will put that request on hold, and fire up a request for the `kmod` subsystem to load the appropriate module. It ends up essentially running `modprobe devname:mapper/control`, which is an alias for `dm_mod` defined in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.alias`, collected from metadata in kernel module files by `depmod` at kernel installation or boot time.

Once the module is loaded and initialized (and it has created the expected device node), the access attempt is resumed and executed, just as if the device node had been there all along.

> which specific `udev` rule creates the file `/dev/mapper/control`?

There might be no `udev` rule at all for this device node, or just some distribution-specific rules to tweak the permissions of the resulting device. When the `dm_mod` kernel module is initializing, it uses the `misc_register()` kernel function to start the device node creation process, **and the kernel code gets to specify the default name and other default parameters for it**. Since `/dev/mapper/control` is a standard static device name for controlling the device-mapper subsystem, there is usually no reason to change the defaults much.

> which specific `udev` rule creates `/dev/dm-x` files?

Again, `udev` does not initiate the creation of devices - the initiative comes from the in-kernel device-mapper subsystem when it calls the kernel function `register_blkdev()`. Once the device-mapper has specified it wants to create a device (**with a specified default name and other default properties**), `udev` can only adjust the parameters of that request and chain other actions to the device event and then fulfill the device node creation request according to the kernel's request + udev rules, using user-space `mknod()` system call.

If there are no udev rules applicable to the request, then `udev` will just create the device with the default name, ownership, permissions and other properties as specified by the device-mapper kernel code. Some of these parameters may have been dictated by the higher-level subystem (i.e. LVM here) when it requested the creation of a new mapping.

You could create any number of udev rules for a new device, but unless some kernel code makes a call to register a device matching the parameters of those rules, those rules would just sit idle, doing nothing.

The modern kernel functions `register_blkdev()` and `register_chrdev()` will let the caller only specify the name of the device, as the long-term goal is to make most/all device major/minor numbers dynamically assigned and let udev deal with assignment of any permissions. But the older `misc_register()` allows specifying the entire device structure, allowing the creation of devices with static major/minor node numbers and other attributes.

To paraphrase Mass Effect 2: the kernel decides *when* to create a device; `udev` decides *how* to create a device node for it.

Comment: Thanks for the quite clear answer, which explained a lot, especially on the module loading via kmod. I also saw that mapper/control line in modules.alias file, meaning it is dm_mod that creates that node. I am still not sure how /dev/dm-x are created though. Maybe my question is more general, is there a kernel function that is responsible to 1. create a device node in /dev, and 2. create device in /sys/devices? And, a device node(not a symlink) in /dev and /sys/devices are always generated together?

Comment: I can see that `device_add()` kernel function creates device related folders/node both in `/sys/devices` and in `/dev`. However in `/drivers/md/dm-ioctl.c`, the back end of the `ioctl()` call to the control node `/dev/mapper/control`, the function that deals with `DM_DEV_CREATE` is `dev_create()`, but there is no call to `device_add()`/`device_register()`/`register_blkdev()`...

Comment: So you are saying kernel device-mapper emits a uevent 'add', which triggers `udev`, and calls `mknod` from userspace to create a node? On a debian machine, in 55-dm.rules, the comments do say 'The rules also create nodes named dm-x in /dev', but I do not understand which line does that, and I only see symlinks being created, not the orignal dm-x nodes though.

Comment: As far as I understand, that is a poorly worded comment: when those rules are being executed, device-mapper has already called for a device to be created, so the only thing the rules can affect is what attributes the device-to-be created will have. Perhaps the comment has not been really reviewed since the early forms of `udevd` before `systemd`: those had certain liberties (e.g. the ability to modify the actual kernel-dictated device node name instead of just creating aliases) that modern `systemd-udevd` does not have. Note that the copyright notice at the beginning is dated 2009.

Comment: Thanks again for reply. Assuming those comments in the udev dm.rules files are outdated, what would be a good example of the scenario you described - kernel's 'add' uevent triggers udev to make a mknod() call from userspace?

Comment: That's basically what `udevd` always does for any 'add device' uevents that arrive to it, every time. Apparently the `devtmpfs` driver may actually auto-create the device with kernel defaults directly (to simplify early boot situations where `udevd` is not yet running), and rely on `udevd` to finalize the job by adjusting the device node's ownership and permissions according to the system's permission policy (i.e. udev rules).

Comment: forgive me sounding like a broken record... but my understanding is, the only chance that udev can call mknod() is through a RUN clause, is that correct? I did a grep in rules.d/ folder and didn't hit any rule that calls mknod(). OR, do you mean device creation(calling mknod) is not reflected in rules files, it's something the udevd daemon does on its own whenever 'add' event arrives? If so, then udevd has to check whether the device node was already created by kernel/devtmpfs in order to avoid duplication, correct?

Comment: Another question... in 55-dm.rules, the first line is `KERNEL=="device-mapper", NAME="mapper/control"`. In udev man page it says that 'The name of a device node cannot be changed by udev, only additional symlinks can be created.', but if that's true, what does this rule actual do?

Comment: https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter09/udev.html Quoting the LFS, 'Device files are created by the kernel by the devtmpfs filesystem. ... A short time later, the kernel will send a uevent to udevd. ... udevd will create additional symlinks to the device node, or change its permissions, owner, or group, or modify the internal udevd database entry (name) for that object.' This description is consistent with kernel's device_add() function. So it is kernel that adds device nodes in /dev, while udevd can only modify the node?